# Check to see if a new moderator message has been sent within the last few minutes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, account-suspension, moderator-messages

Today (and it's not the first time I've observed this), Tim and I suspended and sent a moderator message to the same user within one second of each other.

Could the user messaging/suspension moderator tools be modified to warn us if a new moderator action has been taken against a user within something like the last 5-10 minutes? It doesn't necessarily need to stop us from sending the message, but just pop up a warning so we can go and have a look before hitting the notify button.

Otherwise it looks like we're harassing a user and doesn't seem very professional.

Comment: To me, it looks like we've got two moderators that are very *on the ball*. Good job, guys. (But such a feature couldn't hurt anyway, I suppose.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, I was talking to Rebecca about this yesterday. This has been implemented, pending build; the following applies to moderators only:

- the last contact time is displayed on the screen for both new messages and replies
- if a new message is posted before you submit, the moderator is told about it (the operation is cancelled)

Also, to clarify the point that these messages are to the *user* (not a private mod-to-mod channel), the text of the reply button has been reworded to cite the user's name. Occasionally people got that wrong...