# Moderator message tool discards my message, if another moderator simultaneously sends the user a private message

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, account-suspension, moderator-messages

As a moderator on a SE site, I recently observed behavior that merited a suspension.  I took the time to write a lengthy, detailed private moderator message to the user, to explain the reasons for the suspension and explain how the user could contribute productively when they returned.

However, another moderator beat me to it: they saw the same behavior and suspended the user while I was in the process of writing my message, sending their suspension before I finished writing my message.  When I finished writing my message and clicked the 'Notify User' button, I was greeted with the following error message:

> A more recent message has been posted about this user; please review this and retry if appropriate

That's all reasonable.  Except.... the system discarded my carefully written moderator message.  Pressing the back button didn't restore it, and the system didn't save it anywhere.

In this situation, the system should either save a copy of the message I wrote somewhere so that I can recover it; or else not let me press 'Notify User' to leave that page if it's going to discard my message and throw it in the trash.

(Separately: if one moderator is already on the page and composing a private message to some user, the page should probably warn any other moderator that begins the process of sending a private message to that user.)

(This might be a side effect of [Check to see if a new moderator message has been sent within the last few minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103331/160917).)

Comment: [Possibly the same root cause](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284376/mod-message-lost-to-network-glitch)

Comment: Heh. I think I might know what caused that error message to be created - there was a case a while back on another site when a mod and a CM both messaged the same user nearly simultaneously.

Comment: On a more constructive note, I suggest having a copy of the mod message in an open text document (maybe even writing it up there) and not closing that document until the message has been sent. I do this all the time with important emails etc.; it's a kind of security against browser crashing or internet connection failure as well as this bug.